# SVG tref -xlink:href not working - able to change x,y coord but not textcontent : need fix

Tags: html, text, svg

i am able to change x,y coord of text thru set attr ... but not the textcontent thru tref seems that xlink:href is not working; is it because its called in jsp frames

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics
    /SVG/1.1    
    DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function ichange() {
      var vx100=420; var vy100=100;
      var res=vx100.valueOf(); var newv="budhan";
      document.getElementById("tts").setAttribute("x", res);//works
      document.getElementById("tts").setAttribute("y", vy100);//works
      tts.textContent="Mercury";//does not work
      alert(tts.textContent);
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <BODY>
    <form>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Change Dimensions" onclick="ichange();"/>
    </form>

    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org
    /1999/xlink"     version="1.1" width="1100" height="800" >
    <defs>
    <text id="theText">Mercury</text>
      </defs>

      <text id="tts" x="50" y="80" font-size="17" fill="red">Sun </text>
      <text id="tts" x="100" y="130" font-size="23" fill="black"><tref  
                                              xlink:href="#theText"/> </text> 
      <%--tref is not working .. basically need to replace string Sun with 
      String mercury--%>
    </svg>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well I got it working by using the "Use" property ....

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been removed from the spec and is therefor not implemented.
([More infos](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=273171))
The [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) element is a good alternative.